# Command PLAYER_SET_DATA_SOURCE completed with an error or info PVMFErrNotSupported in android

Tags: android

I am using the MediaPlayer to play some .mp3 files.  The files seem to
play correctly, however, every time I play one I see the following in
LogCat:

```
07-17 17:30:40.298: VERBOSE/SongPath(294): Songlist/data/data/com.bluepallabs.musicbank/haihai/Oopirage.mp3
07-17 17:30:40.387: WARN/MediaPlayer(294): info/warning (1, 26)
07-17 17:30:40.418: ERROR/PlayerDriver(30): Command PLAYER_SET_DATA_SOURCE completed with an error or info PVMFErrNotSupported
07-17 17:30:40.418: ERROR/MediaPlayer(294): error (1, -4)
07-17 17:30:40.427: WARN/PlayerDriver(30): PVMFInfoErrorHandlingComplete
07-17 17:30:40.518: INFO/MediaPlayer(294): Info (1,26)
07-17 17:30:40.528: ERROR/MediaPlayer(294): Error (1,-4)
```

As I am playing the above songpath in emulator.I am getting issue please provide any code avaible to solove this issue.
As I am using the code as:

```
player.reset(); 

songpath=/data/data/com.bluepallabs.musicbank/haihai/Oopirage.mp3                       
player.setDataSource(SongPath);
player.prepareAsync();
```

Thnak in advance.
teja

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`info/warning(1,26)` is just a notification that error handling has started.

`error(1, -4)` is an Error due to the request not being supported

Try making your songpath a String then passing it into the media player like:

```
player.reset(); 

String songpath = "/data/data/com.bluepallabs.musicbank/haihai/Oopirage.mp3"                      
player.setDataSource(songpath);
player.prepareAsync();
```

Comment: Hey Kenny,I am using the above code.I am getting the same issue.As I downloaded the song in /data/data/com.bluepallabs.musicbank/haihai/Oopirage.mp3 path now I want to take the same that path and play the download song.Please suggest me how I has place that downloaded path to play song.Thanks in advance

Comment: It would seem that your path may be incorrect. Double check the file exists before trying to play it, a quick google or search on this site will show you how to do that. If your file is online perhaps take a look at streaming the file rather than downloading it then playing. Take a look at this page for examples http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/index.html

Comment: HiKenny,                                                            
File file = new File("/data/data/com.bluepallabs.musicbank/haihai/Chinnadho.mp3");
boolean exists = file.exists();
It is show that file is exists.
Uri myUri =Uri.parse("/data/data/com.bluepallabs.musicbank/haihai/Chinnadho.mp3"); // initialize Uri here
mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), myUri);
mediaPlayer.prepare();  
I am getting same exception
Command PLAYER_SET_DATA_SOURCE completed with an error or info PVMFErrNotSupported.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please suggest me can we place the download song in that path in application or How we can store path with in application.Thanks in advance

Comment: Hey Kenny,It is working fine now by changing the path             String songpath = "/sdcard/haihai/Oopirage.mp3".Thank you.